# How can I check if I can add word into 2D array length?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I need to check if the String word can be added on the array length, without lose any character out of bounds.
Right now when I add some String words it goes out of the length and I don't know how to fix that.

Right now I fill an 2D array with (*) and I want to add words like *"schedule"* but when I add the word in rows and columns like 2, 5 the word goes out of bounds and print:

---

***relax**
*****sche*
*ridiculo*
*******ta*

And the rest characters of the word disappear.

```java
public class WordSearch {

    private static int rows = 5;
    private static int columns = 10;
    char board[][] = new char [rows][columns];

    public WordSearch(){
        for(int row=0; row<rows; row++){
            for(int col=0; col<columns; col++){
                board[row][col] = '*';
            }
        }
    }

    public void addWord(String word, int position, int x , int y) {

        switch(position){
            case 0:
                for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
                    if(y + 1 >= board[x].length){
                        continue;
                    } else if(board[x][y] == '*'){
                        board[x][y++] = word.charAt(i);
                    } else {
                        board[x][y++] = word.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
                    if(x + 1 >= board[y].length){
                        continue;
                    } else if(board[x][y] == '*'){
                        board[x++][y] = word.charAt(i);
                    } else {
                        board[x++][y] = word.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Give 0 to add word horizontally, or 1 vertically");
            }
            
        }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your exact requirement. Can you elaborate? What is a row or column representing in your row matrix? Can you provide sample inputs along with the expected and actual outputs?

Answer (score 0):

in the `switch` statements and its `case` code block,

```
case 0:
                for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
                    if(y + 1 >= board[x].length){
                        continue;
                    } else if(board[x][y] == '*'){
                        board[x][y++] = word.charAt(i);
                    } else {
                        board[x][y++] = word.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                break;
```

the sentence

```
board[x][y++] = word.charAt(i);
```

after excuting it ,  the variable y will then  continue add 1;
and when excuting the next `if` statements , the y will add 1 again;

so you should change the `if` statements to `if(y >= borad[x].length)`
like this

```
            case 0:
                for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
                    if(y >= board[x].length){
                        continue;
                    } else if(board[x][y] == '*'){
                        board[x][y++] = word.charAt(i);
                    } else {
                        board[x][y++] = word.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
                    if(x  >= board[y].length){
                        continue;
                    } else if(board[x][y] == '*'){
                        board[x++][y] = word.charAt(i);
                    } else {
                        board[x++][y] = word.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public void addWord(String word, int position, int x, int y) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() && y < columns; i++)
            board[x][y++] = word.charAt(i);
        break;
    case 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() && x < rows; i++)
            board[x++][y] = word.charAt(i);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Give 0 to add word horizontally, or 1 vertically");
    }
}
```

and

```
addWord("abcdefghijkl", 0, 1, 1);
for (char[] row : board)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

output:

```
[*, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *]
[*, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]
[*, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *]
[*, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *]
[*, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *]
```